# Transparency and click through in Avalonia

Tags: .net, cross-platform, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am thinking about porting my app made in WPF to Avalonia.

My first requirement is to enable click-through transparency (same as `<Window Background="{x:Null}" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"` in WPF).

I've tried this, but it doesn't look like it works (at least on Windows).

```
ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1"
TransparencyBackgroundFallback="Transparent"
Background="{x:Null}"
```

The target OS's will be Windows, macOS, and Linux. So before installing it in a virtual machine or buying a new device, I need to know if it's possible to have that feature in all OSs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `IsHitTestVisible="False"` is what you're looking for. When I set this property of a `Grid` my mouse seems to go through whatever's inside the grid.

I found it here: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5664